# Как правильно завершить родительский процесс раньше дочернего?

Tags: c

Здравствуйте. 
У меня есть код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
main()
{
    extern int errno;
    extern char* sys_errlist[];
    pid_t pid;
    int rv;
    switch(pid=fork()) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            printf(" CHILD: This is child-process!\n");
            printf(" CHILD: My PID -- %d\n", getpid());
            printf(" CHILD: My parent PID -- %d\n", getppid());
            sleep(3);
            printf(" CHILD: My new parent PID -- %d\n", getppid());
            printf(" CHILD: Exit!\n");
            exit(rv);
        default:
            printf("PARENT: This is parent-process!\n");
            printf("PARENT: My PID -- %d\n", getpid());
            printf("PARENT: My child PID %d\n",pid);
            printf("PARENT: Exit!\n");
    }
}
```

Мне надо чтобы родительский процесс завершался раньше дочернего.
Я практически уверен, что код работает не правильно, так как вывод дает следующее:

```
PARENT: This is parent-process!
PARENT: My PID -- 943
PARENT: My PID -- 943
PARENT: My child PID -- 944
PARENT: Exit!
CHILD: This is child-process!
CHILD: My PID -- 944
CHILD: My parent PID -- 1
CHILD: My new parent PID -- 1
CHILD: Exit!
```

Помогите пожалуйста исправить.

Comment: А в чем причина сомнений? По-моему, все правильно.

Comment: По-моему, только My new parent PID должен быть равен 1, а My parent PID должен быть равен пид родителя, т.к родитель еще не должен был завершиться

Comment: А кто у нас там с pid==1? (по крайней мере в unix-like'ах)

Comment: Дружище, а зачем тебе нужны именно процессы (process)? Довольно серьезная штука, мощная, но для большинства задач подойдут и потоки (threads). Там есть много плюшек, разделяемая память, удобная синхронизация на готовых примитивах вроде мьютексов и семафоров. Если тебе нужно выполнять несколько дел одновременно и параллельно - подойдут и те и другие, но с потоками (threads) проще работать и проще связывать их между собой.

Answer (score 1):

[[@Bloomfield](/users/16430/bloomfield)](/users/16430/bloomfield), вполне допустимо (исправлять тут нечего). Родитель завершился до вызова `getppid()` и удивляться тут нечему. (Кстати, если запустить 100 раз при разной фоновой нагрузке, то результат каждый раз тот же самый?)

Конечно, в таких вопросах надо бы указывать ОС и количество ядер в компе.

Кстати, почему Вы решили, что после `fork()` сразу начнет исполняться код в `child`, а продолжение исполнения `parent` будет отложено?

--

pid == 1 это системный процесс `init`. Он становится "родителем" для всех сирот и после их завершения прибирает их останки (*zombie*, *defunct* (в разных системах их обозначат по разному) после `exit()` в `child` и до `wait()` в родителе), т.е. `struct rusage` -- ту информацию, которую родитель получает по `wait3()`.